# Buildfire: How can I get my plugin to match the rest of the app?

Tags: buildfire

I am making a new plugin and I want it to match the rest of the app in terms of styles, fonts, colors, etc. Is there anyway that buildfire accounts for this situation? I read that including bootstrap might help but I do not know in what way specifically.

Answer (score 0):

BuildFire's SDK automatically injects CSS into your plugin unless you specifically ask not to. If you develop your plugin using standard Bootstrap guidelines then thats all you have to do.

That being said if you want to get a JSON object back with all the appearance settings you can do so through the SDK. See more here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Appearance#buildfireappearancegetappthemecallback

If you want to turn off the auto-injection of theme or bootstrap you can do so through meta tags. See more here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-MetaTags

I hope this helps